# Why am I getting an existance error in prolog

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog

I'm trying to call a function in prolog, and I keep getting the same error and I can't understand why.

```
(GameOption =:= 1 -> play_game(4); GameOption =:= 2 -> playgamevscomputer(4))
```

```
playgamevscomputer(X):-
    initial_board(X, Board),
    displaygamevscomputer(X, Board, red).
```

```
! Existence error in user:playgamevscomputer/1
! procedure user:playgamevscomputer/1 does not exist
! goal:  user:playgamevscomputer(4)
```

I tried changing the name, and body of the function but nothing seems to work

Comment: At a guess, you have a syntax error somewhere in the code before `playgamevscomputer(X):-` and so that is not being read properly. Or you haven't saved and reloaded so the code you see isn't what's running, or something of that nature? Are there any other errors or warnings anywhere?

Comment: Show what source you save in what file, how you load it from Prolog, and how you run the query.